# Writing a text file in memory without storing to disk

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of string as input, which I need to put into a text file, and then put that text file into an encrypted ZIP archive. I want to do this in two steps:

1. Create a text file and get its bytes
2. Write the bytes into the archive using a zip library

However, there is one main requirement: For security reasons I am **not allowed to write the text file to disk**!

I've been playing around with memory streams and stream writers etc. but can't seem to figure it out. I'd prefer UTF8 encoding.

```
private byte[] GenerateTextFile(List<string> contents)
{
    // Generate a text file in memory and return its bytes
}
```

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Not really sure, but you could try to use Memory Mapped Files?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here, a text *file* is just an encoding of text into bytes, wouldn't this just be what you want: `byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Join(Environment.Newline, contents))` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an easy one, you should concat all the strings into one and then call `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`

To concat the strings you can use:

```
string.Join(delimiter, contents)
```

If you don't need the delimeter just remove it, otherwise you probably need to use a `\n`

So you would have this method:

```
private byte[] GenerateTextFile(List<string> contents)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Join(delimiter, contents));
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `String.Join` instead of `Aggregate`?

Comment: Ok, that's another option probably simpler. I will change the answer.

Comment: Definitely use `String.Join` instead. It's not only cleaner (API was made for exactly that use case) but also faster (uses `StringBuilder`).